# How to delete an svn imported files by mistake

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am very new to the SVN and i was provided with the SVN URL and the
credentials. I have create a folder named SVN repo and some files in
that  and I have click on SVN import as I thought that SVN import
would get the files in my SVN repo Directory and have even provided
the username and password. As i came to now that SVN chekout will get
the files in my specified directory , I have done SVN checkout with
specific URL, it even downloaded the folder SVN repo which was created
by me. So my local folder got added in the SVN repo.I did not even did
SVN commit for that folders. Could you please let me know how can I
remove that SVN repo folder which was created by me? As i am using the
tortoise SVN, please guide me how can i delete the imported files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing to worry about, if you haven't committed anything.
Simply delete the folder from your local.

To check, go to SVN URL and see if you find anything from your local machine checked into SVN.

if yes, do SVN update on your local folder and delete the required folder and commit again.

Comment: could u please explain me in detail as i am very new to this and worried about anything will happen to the server data. I have deleted the folder from my local. after that what should i do

Answer (score 0):

Use: `TortoiseSVN` → `Delete to remove files or folders from Subversion`.

Comment: I had deleted the folders. after that what should i do

Comment: Ya updated as well. should i do svn commit . I am very new to this. Please guide me

Comment: Are you using SVN with Visual Studio?

Comment: tortoise svn. I have deleted the files using -> rght click on folder->tortoise svn->delete.. Now what should i do next

Comment: Well I can only tell you that:

1. Commit will replace the head version code to your working code. You can commit it once you are aware and assured about the final code you update. Commit is preferred when you add or update a complete and running code.
2. Update will replace your code with head version code.

There is so much for you to learn. Search the steps involved for SVN operations in google.

Comment: ok thanks . I am not able to make both answers are correct. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can take checkout again of that folder if you have not committed delete to SVN.
If you did delete and commit to SVN from trunk, then you can retrieve last version from tag.